# How do I force macOS to always save file extension?

Tags: macos, finder, firefox, file-extensions

When saving a file without an extension not even OS X is able to open that file anymore. Still it is very easy to accidentally save a file without an extension.

Example: When using Firefox and you save an image with the "Save image as..." context menu, the whole filename including the extension is marked for renaming and as soon as I entered a custom name the extension is gone and I have to reenter it.

[image: Screenshot: Save As... menu from Firefox]

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is the way Firefox handles the "Save as..." action. When using Chrome or Safari  there is no issue.

There is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=426680) since 2008, but the status is still 'NEW'.

The only solution I see at the moment is to select the name (**unnamed**.png) and only edit that part in the text area.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide common filename extensions, so in the save dialog no filename extension will be shown.
In a finder window, open preferences from `Finder` menu. Uncheck `Show all filename extensions`.

Comment: Thank you.While that is a valid option, I need to see file name extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option...

Where the option exists to **Save As** you can always drag images directly to your desktop, or to a folder on your dock (assuming Firefox isn't running fullscreen). The dragged files are saved complete with their file extensions. This would offer an immediate workaround to your problem until Firefox's save behaviour is corrected, assuming the devs ever get around to fixing it...

Comment: When I leave the file name untouched, there would not be a problem. I could just click "save". But thank you.

Comment: It's the workflow I've adopted for precisely this reason - renaming files *after* saving them gives you the option in Finder to undo a name change, should you need it, and you don't have the overwritten extension issue. Dragging is also considerably quicker than right-clicking, going to the Save As menu item and then confirming the save location. Works for me anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly in my opinion Apple went a little too far the other direction on this. When I try to save a .img file from a website, if I have "Show all file extensions" turned off in Finder> Preferences> Advanced, then it automatically renames the file with a .dmg extension, which is NOT the same thing and most applications that work with .img files don't understand or allow selecting a .dmg file in their file browser.

Luckily the fix is simply to check the box for "Show all file extensions" and then just make sure you don't remove an existing extension when downloading from a website, if a download doesn't have an extension, you can add .pdf as the Preview application can handle almost every type of text/image/pdf/video out there, and if it can't, then you probably need to use a command line tool like `file` to guess at the type of file it REALLY is. `file --help` in Terminal will get you started.

One thing to note is that file extensions are primarily for humans, computers can use "magic" file headers or a mime type examination to figure out what program can handle a file, but humans think we know best, which is why we want to manage or override "file handlers", but often things "just work" if we don't go messing with them too much.